# VM heap size set below hardware specified minimum of 128MB

Tags: android

I am getting this error when i tired launching the emulator. Any suggestions?

emulator: WARNING: VM heap size set below hardware specified minimum of 128MB
emulator: WARNING: Setting VM heap size to 128MB
emulator: WARNING: Classic qemu does not support SMP. The hw.cpu.ncore option from your config file is ignored.
emulator: device fd:684

Answer (score 8):

Edit ADV to set value 128 or more than 128 at VM heap of memory options

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Refer to [Managing your AVD's](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/devices/managing-avds.html)

Set the VM Heap of your Emulator to 256mb or 512mb

If you are using a command line initiated emulator, follow this:
[Running your application](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html)

Lastly ensure you have an Intel CPU, and HAXM configured properly.
[Setting up HAXM](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows)

Comment: Thank you, I overcome that VM heap size WARNING  Now I am getting emulator: WARNING: Crash service did not start
emulator: WARNING: Classic qemu does not support SMP. The hw.cpu.ncore option from your config file is ignored. any suggestion. thankyou

Comment: Are you on a MacOS, Windows or Ubuntu? Are you running an AMD cpu or an Intel CPU

Comment: first remove all AVD's that you have configured, and reinstall HAXM. Then restart your machine, and create a new emulator. If that does not work then you have an issue with your HAXM

Comment: Thankyou for your suggestions but till now Iam getting  emulator: WARNING: Crash service did not start emulator: WARNING: Classic qemu does not support SMP. The hw.cpu.ncore option from your config file is ignored.    warnings

Comment: Is there any need of Intel graphics media driver and Intel management engine interface driver for this one

Comment: Thankyou for your suggestion