# android emulator not working after haxm upgrade

Tags: android, emulation, haxm

Android emulator not working after HAXM upgrade

Log:

```
emulator: WARNING: Crash service did not start

emulator: WARNING: VM heap size set below hardware specified minimum of 80MB
emulator: WARNING: Setting VM heap size to 256MB
emulator: WARNING: Classic qemu does not support SMP. The hw.cpu.ncore option from your config file is ignored.
emulator: WARNING: cache image already in use, changes will not persist!

Creating filesystem with parameters:
    Size: 69206016
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 4224
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 1024
    Label:
    Blocks: 16896
    Block groups: 1
    Reserved block group size: 7
Created filesystem with 11/4224 inodes and 1302/16896 blocks
WARNING: SD Card image already in use: C:\Users\User01\.android\avd\Tab_API_23.avd/sdcard.img
emulator: warning: opening audio output failed
```

Comment: its error because for in VM you give less memory to that device

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VM heap size set below hardware specified minimum of 128MB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36686093/vm-heap-size-set-below-hardware-specified-minimum-of-128mb)

Comment: How to solve  : WARNING: Crash service did not start                  WARNING: Classic qemu does not support SMP. The hw.cpu.ncore option from your config file is ignored.

Comment: follow this steps 
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/emulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You have to options:**

1. increase the memory for HAXM i.e. "re-running the HAXM installer to set a higher memory limit"
2. pick an AVD that needs less RAM. i.e. "try creating an AVD that requires less RAM"*

for more follow this link steps 
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/emulator

Comment: Still emulator not working...it stops after  emulator: WARNING: Crash service did not start
Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x40000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
audio: Failed to create voice `goldfish_audio'
qemu-system-i386.exe: warning: opening audio output failed
audio: Failed to create voice `goldfish_audio_in'
qemu-system-i386.exe: warning: opening audio input failed
console on port 5554, ADB on port 5555

Answer (score 0):

If above solution not work for you, then open the AVD Manager

Check the Size on Disk - if memory is more then click on Actions -> Wipe Data

Start emulator, It will work!!

Hope it will work for you